# How to reset buttons color?

Tags: java, android

I have a game, with 16 buttons. After each button click I set a color to the button. Now, after 16 clicks, my activity reloads. I want to reset all button's color to start values after that reload. My buttons have some transparency, set in buttons.xml. Here's my code where I count button clicks and after 16 of them I reload activity. How to reset color of all buttons, but to maintain that transparency and settings from buttons.xml?

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            private Button buttonClicked;
            private int counter = 0;
            private int numberOfClicks = 0;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                numberOfClicks++;
                if (brojacKlikova < 10) {

                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFCC99));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
                } else {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
                        Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        counter = counter + 5;
                        score.setText("Points: " + counter);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));
                        button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    }
                    // remember to reset background of button and buttonClicked before
                    buttonClicked = null;
                }
                }else{

                nextQuestion();

         }
            }
     };
```

And here's buttons.xml if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#254117"/>

            <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>

            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#98800000" />


        </shape>
    </item>
        <item>
        <shape>

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#254117"/>

            <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>

            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#60000000" />


        </shape>
    </item>
 </selector>
```